# PHP PGP check keysize before import

Tags: php, public-key, pgp

What's the best way, to check the keysize of a PGP key, before importing it using the PGP PHP library?
I would like to allow only keys with a size of 2048 or 4096 bits.
I'm using this PHP library:

[PGP lib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php)

My code at the moment:

```
//import private key
$imp_info = $gpg->import($request->public_key);
```

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make any sense but I also don't think it is relevant.

Comment: @JamesKPolk  edited.